# Blender VTK nodes add-on question for v2.79b for scientific visualization for volume rendering from VTK data

Tags: rendering

I am new to blender and I am intending to use it for scientific visualization of my data from ParaView. I am able to perform renderings with my surface data, but to import volume rendering from VTK data, I was looking to use the add-on developed here:

https://bvtknodes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/BVTKNodes.html#installation-of-vtk-for-blender

with the explicit add-on for my version of Blender (2.79b) on Windows 10 here:
https://github.com/tkeskita/BVtkNodes

I followed the instructions to first install the VTK libraries/update them. Then, I followed the install procedure for adding add-ons into Blender.

The problem is I don't quite understand the error (see image). Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Also is there a better way to visualize volume rendering data from applications like ParaView? (the standard approach is to use .x3d or .ply import but that applies for surface data only not volume data).

Sorry if this is a trivial question/repeated and or formatted incorrectly, this is my first time on here. Thanks for the help.[image]

Comment: The error indicates that you've installed the add-on version for Blender 2.8x, which is not compatible with Blender 2.79b. The type annotations where introduced to the Python API in Blender 2.80, as shown [here](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Addons) in the section "Class Property Registration".

Comment: Ah understood. I will try to find the correct installation then. If anyone has a better suggestion for volume rendering it would be appreciated as currently this is the most suitable method I have found. Thank you Robert.

Comment: The question is what file format you can export to / what kind of data you want to render. If you're able to run Blender 2.83 or later on your hardware and are able to export the volume as OpenVDB file, that would be an alternative (*Add > Volume > Import OpenVDB*).

Comment: Yes, it appears that export is not possible from Paraview. I was able to find the correct add on for 2.79b here: https://github.com/esowc/sci_vis

Comment: The problem is now that the new setting do not load into the tree. I think I need vtk version 8.2.0 but I have 8.1.2 is there a way to uninstall and reinstall this library? Further the only exportable options for the data are: vtk, vti, xmf, json for data. For scene export: vtkjs, x3d, etc. For the surface export, I use the export scene x3d format. Not sure if this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with VTK nor the importer add-on, so I can't really help you if the add-on is not compatible with the VTK version.